# Query for nested groups and push in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying mongoDB for first time. I need to aggregate my data from one collection to another. Trying this code but it doesn't execute because of unexpected error :

> "unexpected expression $group"

```
db.import.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                day: "$Day",
                month: "$Month",
                year: "$Year"
            },
            manufacturers: {
                $push: {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            manID: "$Man_ID",
                            man_name: "$Man_Name"
                        },
                        types: {
                            $push: {
                                model_name: "$Model_name",
                                body_type: "$Body_type"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "output_doc" }
], {
    allowDiskUse: true,
    cursor: {}
});
```

Expected Output:

```
["$Day","$Month","$Year",
    ["$Man_ID","$Man_Name", 
       ["$Model_name","$Body_type"]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just push your new `_id` field and create your `types` array without any operator :

```
db.import.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            day: "$Day",
            month: "$Month",
            year: "$Year"
        },
        manufacturers: {
            $push: {
                _id: {
                    manID: "$Man_ID",
                    man_name: "$Man_Name"
                },
                types: [{ model_name: "$Model_name", body_type: "$Body_type" }]
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Hello Bertrand. I tried this query, It runs for a while and then connection terminates to the database instance. Tried restarting the connection and run some other basic queries. It works fine with those queries. I tried running this query again, results into connection drop again. I am not sure if it is the query or its because of my collection size which has like 1.7m records.